# 3 Tier connectivity in Java

Tags: java, database, 3-tier

I' am building a application program in Java EE as a front end and MySQL as a back end for database...

I wanted to establish a 3-tier connectivity between the database and the forms in Java.

What all would i need? Will i need an application program server something like glassfish or apache tomcat???  is it related to hibernate, spring or servelets or javabeans or something else?? Iam realy confused and want to start right from the begging.

Could you please guide me?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is very broad question, I highly suggest you to go through basics of Java EE http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/javaeetutorial6.pdf

Answer (score 0):

that is a very wide scope question, but still putting simply

you mentioned the two tiers

1: java forms : you can use JSP for it

3 : MySQL database , the backend

now about the layer 2, you can use servelets. the servelets.

Yes you would need a server, like tomcat.

I would recommend studying about MVC`s. You could very well model your application using one like struts.